# Does Rift support user interface customisation?

Tags: rift

What level of user interface customisation does Rift support? Is it possible to move/resize/remove individual user interface elements?

Does Rift support addons, similar to the way that World of Warcraft does? I am intending to go down the familiar route of being the group/raid healer/support character so some kind of mouse over healing addon (similar to VuhDo or Grid) would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is yes.

http://www.riftui.com/addons.php

Whilst Rift doesn't have as many community developed addons as the big fish like wow etc, it does have a nice tidy pack of customization and enhancement options provided via third party users that seem to (at first glace, I haven't utilized these myself) mimic the best UI addons from other similar games.

Healing frames happens to be one of the most popular. (MereHealingFrames)